# Как в коде поменять вставленное изображение в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, pyqt6

У меня вставлено изображение через **.qrc**:

```
self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 210, 451, 191))
self.label_9.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/bolt/Болт1.jpg);")
```

Потом импортируется:

```
import for_bolt
```

Вставлял в *Qt Designer*, как можно это изображение поменять в коде, тоже через **.qrc**?

Comment: Изначально было в импорте так: import for_bolt_rc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . *Qt Designer*:

- Создали форму

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Конвертируем **.ui** в **.py**

  `pyuic5 q1413471.ui -o q1413471_ui.py -x`

2 . Конвертируем файл ресурсов **.qrc** в **.py**

**r1413471.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>off.png</file>
    <file>on.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

```
pyrcc5 r1413471.qrc -o r1413471_rc.py
```

---

**q1413471.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

import r1413471_rc


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(234, 225)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    image: url(:/newPrefix/off.png);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.image_change)
        
        
    def image_change(self, state):
        if state:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {image: url(:/newPrefix/on.png);}")
        else:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {image: url(:/newPrefix/off.png);}")        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]